# Why my string is being split when assigned in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I used the [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3q3wk9chv1vb7xn/preparing_data.py?dl=0) to prepare data in [this .csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy1b16skxfmh4iy/arachnid.csv?dl=0), so that I can later insert the data into MongoDB.

Although 'description' string is originally a continuous string, it's being split when read into the dictionary, resulting in assertion failure:

```
 'description': 'The genus Argiope includes rather large and spectacular '
            'spiders that often have a strikingly coloured abdomen. These '
            'spiders are distributed throughout the world. Most countries '
            'in tropical or temperate climates host one or more species '
            'that are similar in appearance. The etymology of the name is '
            'from a Greek name meaning silver-faced.',
```

Comment: Instead of sharing all your code, please produce a  Minimal, Reproducible Example. Just the parts of the code that actually read the description string into a dictionary.

Comment: The error is not caused by the way the string is split but by a number of inaccuracies in the definition of `first_entry`: the key "classification" (lower case) should be "Classification" (capitalized), the value for "label" should be "Argiope (spider)" instead of "Argiope", the dictionary `first_entry["classification"]` is missing the key "label" with value "Argiope (spider)".

Comment: @Heike Thank you so much for noticing these 2 mistakes. This solved my problem. I lower cased "Classification". Also, I found that I mistakenly added line# 103 "temp_dict[FIELDS['rdf-schema#label']]=line['rdf-schema#label'].strip()", which was undoing the label cleaning that I already did on line# 82-83. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice work @Heike, I am going to vote to close as typo based on your fixes.